# How do I transpose a list of data over a range of dates to individual dates in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

[Example SSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zoP8MhySQW44HptS0pSxgFVsV-kX2sEHNr6xEe3iXE8/edit?usp=sharing)

Hello, I have a data analysis problem i'm not sure how to tackle, please see example google sheet. I have a list of data for the cost of products over a date range; The date range is specified by a start and end date column. I need to write a macro which identifies the cost of a specific product for each day in the date range, and match it to a unique product list by day (sheet2). I honestly don't know where to start as my knowledge of VBA is limited, but i do have some familiarity with the language. Would anyone be able to help me figure out a way to tackle this problem? I already have a macro which generates Sheet2, I just need a way to populate it with the information from sheet1. Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: I'd use a dictionary object to collect and organize the data.

Comment: I definitely overthought this, but a simple sumif actually does the trick. by comparing the title date on the second sheet to the start/end date columns with the expression ["<="&Sheet2!D$1 ] & [">="&Sheet2!D$1 ] I can get what i need. H/o thanks for your help I'll check out the dictionary object, might prove useful for other comparisons